# Jquery load event (with selector) causing request event

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm looking through many posts, but not finding a solution here. I am using jQuery to load a portion of a page. (We have a shared menu across applications, and unfortunately this seems to be the easiest approach to sharing the menu code).

My goal is to use a load command like so:

```
$('#menu').load('//mywebsite.ca/home.html  .selector .menu');
```

This works, however, when looking in Chrome's inspector tool, I see multiple requests for images (which do exist on the site I'm grabbing from) being requested even though they are not contained within my selector / fetched container.

Is there any way to prevent this from occurring, or is this a natural consequence as jQuery parses what it had loaded.

I had the same issue using

```
$.Get / $.ajax
```

and have tried using

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

to see if it changes anything, but it doesnt.

Any tips or tricks are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a natural occurrence. The only possible way to prevent it would be to use $.ajax with type = text and parsing the content as text before converting to html, which is WAY more work than it's worth.